# How to configure the primary_slave in a bond interface created by bond-cni plugin in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, cni

The question is what is exposed in the title, I am trying to create a bond in a kubernetes pod with the [bond-cni](https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/bond-cni) plugin.

The configuration of the plugin is a little bit basic so I have changed the function in which the bond is created:

original function:

```
func createBondedLink(bondName string, bondMode string, bondMiimon string, bondMTU int, failOverMac int, netNsHandle *netlink.Handle) (*netlink.Bond, error) {
    var err error
    bondLinkObj := netlink.NewLinkBond(netlink.NewLinkAttrs())
    bondModeObj := netlink.StringToBondMode(bondMode)
    bondLinkObj.Attrs().Name = bondName
    bondLinkObj.Mode = bondModeObj
    bondLinkObj.Miimon, err = strconv.Atoi(bondMiimon)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to convert bondMiimon value (%+v) to an int, error: %+v", bondMiimon, err)
    }
    if bondMTU != 0 {
        bondLinkObj.MTU = bondMTU
    }
    bondLinkObj.FailOverMac = netlink.BondFailOverMac(failOverMac)

    err = netNsHandle.LinkAdd(bondLinkObj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to add link (%+v) to the netNsHandle, error: %+v", bondLinkObj.Attrs().Name, err)
    }

    return bondLinkObj, nil
}
```

changed function:

```
func createBondedLink(bondName string, bondMode string, bondMiimon string, bondPrimary int, bondArpInterval string, bondArpTargets string, bondMTU int, failOverMac int, netNsHandle *netlink.Handle) (*netlink.Bond, error) {
    var err error
    bondLinkObj := netlink.NewLinkBond(netlink.NewLinkAttrs())
    bondModeObj := netlink.StringToBondMode(bondMode)
    bondLinkObj.Attrs().Name = bondName
    bondLinkObj.Mode = bondModeObj
    bondLinkObj.ArpInterval, err = strconv.Atoi(bondArpInterval)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to convert bondMiimon value (%+v) to an int, error: %+v", bondMiimon, err)
    }
    bondLinkObj.Miimon = 0
    if bondMTU != 0 {
        bondLinkObj.MTU = bondMTU
    }
    bondLinkObj.FailOverMac = netlink.BondFailOverMac(failOverMac)
    bondLinkObj.ArpValidate = netlink.BondArpValidate(3)
    bondLinkObj.ArpIpTargets = []net.IP{net.ParseIP(bondArpTargets)}
    bondLinkObj.Primary = bondPrimary
    err = netNsHandle.LinkAdd(bondLinkObj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to add link (%+v) to the netNsHandle, error: %+v", bondLinkObj.Attrs().Name, err)
    }

    return bondLinkObj, nil
}
```

I have only added the parameters of ArpInterval, ArpIpTargets, ArpValidate and Primary. The thing is that the bond is created correctly execpt the part of configuration of the primary slave. I have see how te plugin creates the bond and the steps are:

- Create the bond.
- Attach links to bond (aggreate slaves to the bond)
- Bring up the bond.

```
bondLinkObj, err := createBondedLink(bondName, bondConf.Mode, bondConf.Miimon, bondConf.MTU, bondConf.FailOverMac, netNsHandle)
if err != nil {
return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to create bonded link (%+v), error: %+v", bondName, err)
}

err = attachLinksToBond(bondLinkObj, linkObjectsToBond, netNsHandle)
if err != nil {
return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to attached links to bond, error: %+v", err)
}

if err := netNsHandle.LinkSetUp(bondLinkObj); err != nil {
return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to set bond link UP, error: %v", err)
}
```

I think the error is that the slaves are added to the bond after the bond is configured and this makes that the primary interface is not configured (due the primary parameter is an integer).

The first thing I have tried is to apply a second time the configuration of the bond once the slaves have been added to the bond (after attachLinksToBond function) using the function LinkModify facilitated by the netlink library. This produces the error

```
error: directory not empty
```

I read the code of the LinkModify function and it is only different to the LinkAdd in the flags that are passed, but I am not sure if this flags accepts in the case of the bond. So I think this function is not prepared to change the configuration of a bond.

The second thing was to change the primary interface as I have done in bonds in the host that was changing the file /sys/class/net/<bond_name>/bonding/primary. The problem is that the cni plugin creates the interfaces in a new netns (network namespace) and I don't know exactly where are supposed to be the file /sys/class/net/<bond_name>/bonding/primary in a determined netns. So I have try to execute in the cni plugin the command:

```
netnsvariable := os.Getenv("CNI_NETNS")
commandnetns := filepath.Base(netnsvariable)
cmd := exec.Command("ip", "netns", "exec", commandnetns, "echo", "tap2", ">", "/sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/primary")
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This configuration don't throws any error but the primary slave is not configured in the bond.

I have spent lot of time thinking about how to be able to overcome this but I don't have more ideas, so I am writing this in the forum as my final hope to find a solution. Thanks in advance guys and sorry for the errors I have could committed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made another search on google and I have found this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649632/linux-bonding-changing-params-if-statically-linked) that I have not find before...

Well, to change the primary slave parameter on a bond that it is a netns is as easy as run the command:

```
ip netns exec <netns_name> ip link set dev <bond_name> type bond primary <primary_slave_name>
```

Sorry if this problem has bother someone, but at the end a solution has been found xD.